# Отображение формы в ИЕ и хроме

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как исправить баг с ИЕ и хромом. Есть поле

```
<input type="image" name="submit"  class="per" value="перезвонить" />
```

В мозиле и опере отображается корректно, а вот в хроме не показывает картинку

CSS

```
per {
    background-image: url("img/per1.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

В IE

[image: IE]

В Хроме

[image: Хром]

В Мозилле

[image: Мозилла]

Comment: У вас еще там и позиционирование хромает.

Comment: Плавает только это форма на странице. Не пойму, что может быть... Вот стиль на инпут `width: 130px;height: 20px;padding: 0 5px;border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;margin-top: 5px;color: #7F7F7F;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, чтобы все в ряд было юзайте **table**. Во-вторых, путь прописывается от корня, т.е. не `img/per1.jpg` а - `/img/per1.jpg`. Input type image не юзал, не юзаю, юзать не собираюсь и вам не советую :)

Answer (score 5):

Очень часто браузеры считают, что если не указан путь от корня до картинки, то его надо считать с места откуда взят стиль. Поставьте путь от корня и еще - просто откройте рисунок в браузерах, чтобы убедиться, что он именно JPG. Часто бывает, что PNG поменяют расширение на JPG и некоторые браузеры сами понимают это, а некоторые - нет, и получается, что рисунка нет

А еще можете просто в кнопку прописать адрес картинки и ширину, раз уж тип рисунка делаете

```
<INPUT TYPE='IMAGE' SRC="partyon.gif" VALUE="Party on..." name='имя кнопки'>
```

Comment: вот если меняют тип элемента с image на submit http://clip2net.com/s/1c3xx в хроме. Ничего не пойму. как сделать нормальную кнопку.. и почему она выше остальной формы